# Finding number of permutations to form lists.

Tags: combinatorics

Want to know how to find number of arrangements for selecting a $5$ member list from $12$ teachers and $14$ students, such that least one student and one teacher must be included?

I find solving it difficult as that would include cases where second person in a category ( two categories: student, teacher) is selected before the first. So, for that reason the strategy of first finding combinations is not applicable, as cannot simply multiply by $5!$.

For illustration, have taken smaller example to form $3$-person list from $4$ teachers and $4$ students.

---

My solution is stated below. Request vetting. Also, is there any other approach to solve the original problem, apart from an extension of the below solution.

Let S1 be the first student selected, T1 be the first teacher selected. Similarly, for S2, T2.

Let, $a_1 = $#ways S1 can be selected,
$b_1 = $#ways T1 can be selected,
$a_2 = $#ways S2 can be selected, 
$b_2 = $#ways T2 can be selected.
Note that if $a_2$ is greater than one, then $b_2=1$, and vice-versa.

The lists of size three can be formed by always having the first person in each category selected first. So, need arrangements with S1 before S2, & T1 before T2.

So, the possible ways are:

1. $a_1a_2b_1\times 2!$, as there can be swap between S2, T1
2. $a_1b_1b_2\times 2!$, as there can
   be swap between S1, T1

Sum of above is :
$(a_1a_2b_1 + a_1b_1b_2)\times 2!= (4C1\times3C1\times4C1 + 4C1\times4C1\times3C1)\times 2!$
$(4\times3\times4+4\times4\times3)\times 2 =96\times 2 = 192$.

Comment: *List* implies that the order matters; is that correct? Or are we just counting *sets* of $5$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, so need permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit easier to count the lists that **don’t** have at least one teacher and one student. There are $5!\binom{12}5$ that have no student and $5!\binom{14}5$ that have no teacher, and there are $5!\binom{26}5$ lists altogether, so ... ?

Comment: It yields the same answer as- finding the combinations based first step, and then multiplying by $5!$. The combinatorics based method would have yielded $(14C1\times 12C4+14C2\times 12C3+14C3\times 12C2+14C4\times 12C1)*5!=62986*5!= 7558320$. Also, your method yields $(65780-2002-792)*5!= 62986*5!$. So, seemingly the justification for matching answer by both approaches is that, as any student is as likely to be the first student selected (similarly, for teacher); so approach based on taking combinations first, then multiplying by $5!$ is equally good. It is a big learning.

Comment: @jiten: That’s right; both work. The main difference is that my approach requires fewer calculations.

Comment: But, then my smaller example would yield $3!(\binom{8}3 - \binom{4}3 - \binom{4}3) = 3!(56 - 4 - 4) = 3!(48) = 288$. So, either your or mine approach is wrong. Mine yields $2.2.48=192$, rather than $3.2.48$.

Comment: @jiten: I didn’t actually check your calculations in detail; I’ll have to go back and take another look.

Comment: @jiten: I see the problem with your small example: you’ve not counted the lists with $2$ students and the teacher first, and you’ve not counted the lists with $2$ teachers and the student last. That accounts for the missing $96$ lists.

Comment: Yes, each of the two cases contributes $48$ permutations i.e. $b1a1a2$ and $b1b2a1$ for case 1 and 2 respectively. So, $48*24 cases were skipped.

Comment: sorry, meant $48*2$ cases were skipped.

Comment: @jiten: That’s okay; I understood what you meant.